# Cheers, people!

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Try make sense of this image below. Good luck!

[image]

Comment: I think everyone new the answer before even looking at the puzzle :P Here’s to 2021!

Comment: Yeah, this was a 'friendly' puzzle :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer:

> Happy New Year

Reasoning:

> The top part of the image represents pieces of a Connect Four board. When rearranged to have a continuous border, they show a board state with only one line of 4 circles in the same color. The squares corresponding to those circles contain the letters RAE YWE NYP PAH. This, when read backwards, gives the answer.

Comment: hell it's like sherlock holmes or something in here. niiiiiiiiiice

Answer (score 11):

This is a

> Connect four game!!!

Reconstructing the grid:

> [image]

If we look at where the game is won:

> [image]

We get an anagram of the message

> **HAPPY NEW YEAR**!! :)

Comment: hell it's like sherlock holmes or something in here. niiiiiiiiiice

Comment: actually it's a very specific type of anagram based on Seren's answer?

Comment: @BCLC I suppose so, but its still an anagram